# Add an option to sort by badge count to /users

Tags: feature-request, badges, user-list

The /users page allows you to sort users based on reputation, votes, with different time windows (week, month, quarter, year, all).

I think it would be cool to have an additional tab that does something similar for badge count.

It would be neat to know who has received the most bages in the last month.

[image: we do need some stinking badges!]